# System.VisualforceException: Modified rows exist in the records collection!

Tags: visualforce, pagination, record

I am displaying the pagination using standardsetController. And it is working but when i try to change the value in my inputtest and i am clicking the next button it is showing error that

> System.VisualforceException: Modified rows exist in the records collection!

Is it is not possible to change the value of the displaying record by using pagination. Please guide me the proper way to get the solution. 
Here is my class

```
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon{
    get{
        if(setCon == null){
           limits = 5;
           String queryString = 'SELECT Name, Id, Languages__c FROM Contact WHERE name != null'; 
           setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(DataBase.getQueryLocator(queryString));
           setCon.setPageSize(limits);
           recNum = setCon.getResultSize();
           SYSTEM.DEBUG('Inside Apex Pages Standard set Controller ' + setCon );
        }

        clone_cont_lst = setCon.getRecords();
        for(Contact c:  clone_cont_lst){
            contMap.put(c.id, c);
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set{

    }

}

public pageReference refresh(){
    setCon = null;
    getContact();
    //setCon.setPageNumber(1);
    return null;

}

public List<Contact> getContact(){



    List<Contact> conLst = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact c: (List<Contact>)setCon.getRecords()){


            conLst.add(c);


    }



    counter = recNum / 5;        
    return conLst;
} 
  public void nextbtn(){
     setCon.Next();
   }
```

my vf page

```
<apex:form >
 <apex:dataTable value="{!Contact}" var="ac" id="paginationID">
      <apex:column headerValue="Name">
          <apex:outputField value="{!ac.Name}"/>
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="Id">
          <apex:outputField value="{!ac.Id}"/>
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="Languages">
          <apex:inputField value="{!ac.Languages__c}"/>
      </apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>

  <apex:commandButton value="FIRST" action="{!fstbtn}" disabled="{!prv}" reRender="paginationID,pgno"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="PRE" action="{!prvbtn}" disabled="{!prv}" reRender="paginationID,pgno"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="NXT" action="{!nextbtn}" disabled="{!nxt}" reRender="paginationID,pgno"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="END" action="{!endbtn}" disabled="{!nxt}" reRender="paginationID,pgno"/>
  <br/><apex:outputText >No of pages {!counter}</apex:outputText>
       <apex:outputText id="pgno">of current page- {!setCon.PageNumber} </apex:outputText>

  </apex:form>
```

please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I highly recommend you look at http://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf - Chapter 4, page 55 for best practices on standardSetControllers

Answer (score 1):

If you study your controller and your VF page code, you have no `update` or `save` code in either one. Even if you did, neither is related to your `pagination` code. You would need to link `update` code to your `pagination` code. If you did that, you'd also want to raise an `alert!` asking if the user wanted to `save` the changes they'd made.

Comment: this error occurs when i click on my next button after making change in my record. Yes the user need to save the change, his requirement is if he made the change in pg 1 and hit next and go to page 2 and then 3 and make change on 3 and when he come back to pg 1 the changed value should be there before saving .. that mean he need it to hold temp before save. As ef now he need to update the current records according to the change he make.

Comment: If you look at your controller you'll see `contMap.put(c.id, c)` which holds a map of what's returned from your queries. Your controller doesn't have any means of holding changes your user makes to pagination views. You'd need to add that functionality to it in order to do what you're asking about.

Comment: As u mentioned about the map i am using i have commented it but i am still facing the same issue. I used map to trace is the records see before and does there any update done. I have not completed it before that i tested it i found this issue. Do you have any idea over this. If i click next button without updating the record it has no problem but if we change this i am facing this issue. Please guide me.

Comment: You really need to look at the documentation. If I'm not mistaken, those records are also part of a `get` related to your query string locator. That puts a `lock` on those records. Until the `lock` is released, they can't be modified outside that querystring/controller.